# Stop rand() code after limited page refreshes

Tags: php, mysql, random

I'm using a code that generate a random word from a database using ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 (not many rows so it runs okay) . Is it possible, using php, to only allow the user to refresh the page a few limited times (either by clicking refresh manually or using a form['submit'] button) and then stopping the random function so it sets to the last value?

I know I can count page visits/refreshes by using sessions/cookies but I'm not sure how to stop the code running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Barely constitutes an answer but too long for a comment - what is it exactly that you don't get?

```
<?php session_start();

// ...

if(!isset($_SESSION['myCounter'])) 
    $_SESSION['myCounter'] = 0;

if($_SESSION['myCounter'] < $myLimit){
    $_SESSION['myCounter']++;
    // Do random DB query 
    $_SESSION['lastResult'] = $dbResult;
}

// Do something with result
echo $_SESSION['lastResult'];

// ...
```

There are even examples on the [manual pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)...

Answer (score 0):

A IF statement would suffice

IF ( pagecount < 3 )

{

```
  Execute code
```

}

ELSE

{

```
   Don't execute code
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag on your PHP Script using a session say, `$_SESSION['runRand'] = 1;`

Run the random word db code only when the above variable is set to **1**.

So when the user runs this script first time...

Store the first random word which was generated from DB into a session variable say `$_SESSION['firstRand']=$randNum;`

So when the user clicks the refresh button or submit, the PHP script gonna load again and a new random word will be generated, now don't store that word, just compare it to the one with the session variable **`$_SESSION['firstRand'];`**

When the user keeps clicking refresh and do the same process again, at some point the random word will match with the $_SESSION['firstRand']; , at that time set the session variable **`$_SESSION['runRand'] = 0;`** . Now , eventhough the user presses the refresh button the random code from DB will not be generated.